# Is it possible to shoot in burst mode/continuous shooting mode on the Ricoh GR III?

Tags: ricoh

Is it possible to shoot in burst mode/continuous shooting mode on the Ricoh GR III?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Refer to pages 74 and 75 of the [operating manual](https://www.ricoh-imaging.co.jp/english/support/man-pdf/gr-3.pdf), which describe **Setting the Drive Mode**, and selecting "Continuous Shooting".

(Thanks to Romeo Ninov and Philip Kendall for finding the manual and reference locations.)